# Boolean values in PHP always evaluate to false?

Tags: php, boolean

I'm working with an API that returns JSON about users in a database.

I'm having some trouble evaluating some boolean values from the user data. I've pulled all my information into an array called `$search_results` - then I loop through the array to check if they have anything listed in the `ok_to_list_donor` field.

If `ok_to_list_donor` is empty, I need to check if we have permission or not. If we do have permission, then I'm going to update the `ok_to_list_donor_field` with their name.

If we don't have permission, I'll update it with AnonymousXXXX where XXXX is their internal ID.

In some cases, they haven't given us explicit permission, nor have they denied us. The value is likely to come back as NULL, so we use Anonymous?XXXX to denote that.

Here's the loop I'm using.

```
foreach ($search_results as $fields) {
// If they don't have an "ok to list donor" value, check if we have permission
    if (empty($fields["donor"]["ok_to_list_donor"])) {
        // If we don't have permission, update as anon
        if ((boolean)$fields["permisson"] === (boolean)false) {
          var_dump($fields["permission"]);
          echo "Update as AnonXXXX";
        }
        // If we do have permission, update the field with name
        elseif ((boolean)$fields["permission"] === (boolean)true) {
          var_dump($fields["permission"]);
          echo "Update as First Name Last Name";
        }
        // The only possible case left
        // If permission is null, it's unclear
        else {
          var_dump($fields["permission"]);
          echo "Update as Anon?XXXX";
        }
    }
}
```

I included the var_dump to check type and value of the `$fields["permission"]` and I'm getting all the values I'd anticipate, however, even when `$fields["permission"]` evaluates to `(bool)true` - I'm seeing my debug output for the `(bool)false` case.

I did the type casting because I was getting this error when I was just comparing `$fields["permission"] === false` and so on and so forth, and wanted to make sure the data from the API was precisely as I expected.

Here's the output I'm seeing:

```
bool(true)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
bool(false)
Update as AnonXXXX
```

Am I doing boolean comparisons incorrectly? New to PHP and not sure if I've missed something big

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` would show you the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first comparison is against `$fields["permisson"]`, not `$fields["permission"]`. There's a simple typo in your your key. Fix that, and all the casting should be able to go away.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo which has been pointed out, but after fixing that all the boolean casts really *need* to go away.

Casting a literal boolean to boolean  like `(boolean)false` is not necessary. It's definitely a boolean. That part is not hurting anything, it's just pointless.

Casting the value you're comparing to boolean is counterproductive to your goal, though.

`(boolean)$fields["permission"]` will convert `null` values to `false`, so if the possible values for `$fields["permission"]` are `true`, `false`, and `null`, the else block will never be reached.